React 19 PropTypes Alternatives
With React 19, PropTypes are removed from React and are being ignored. While the React team recommends using Typescript instead, I believe this is not a complete replacement.
I am using Typescript in my project already, although it has limits, if for some reason Types cannot be fully specified and use some kind of any or as. I also rely heavily on APIs which do not have Type specifications available or also not precise enough.
Using Typescript AND PropTypes was a well recommended practice and it saved me quite some time from running into unexpected behaviors due to missing Typescript warnings.
So my question is, is there any replacement for Type checking at run-time (and not only at compile time) for React 19?

I've generally found typescript to be enough. Where runtime checks are required I tend to use typescript type guards (though that's just a fancy way of saying "if statements") but honestly that's always been enough for our purposes where I work. I have heard people say positive things about Zod for example though. Neither of these are a direct replacement for PropTypes but I think the gaps that TypeScript can't fill with React are rarely React specific gaps but things like API data etc

I have some APIs, which provide JSON data. They are either PHP, or third party. I have written Types how I think they would respond. However, it would be super helpful if Typescript would throw errors in Browser in React Dev Mode if the Types doesn't match to the actual data provided. It is not really a React specific requirement indeed.

I will simply quote the description of the PR that removed propTypes validation:

In general, our recommendation is to use static type checking (e.g. TypeScript). If you'd like to still run propTypes checks, you can do so manually, same as you'd do outside React:
import checkPropTypes from 'prop-types/checkPropTypes';

function Button(props) {
  checkPropTypes(Button.propTypes, props, 'prop', Button.name)
  // ...
}

This could be automated as a Babel plugin if you want to keep these checks implicit. (We will not be providing such a plugin, but someone in community might be interested in building or maintaining one.)

